# How to hide "Create And Edit" button in all form odoo And also "Search More" Button in every line

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to hide "Create and Edit" button in all form

and also I want to show "Search More" button in all form

[image: Hide and Show button for all module]

Currently Im using odoo 10.

Let's see this addons

https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/9.0/web_m2x_options/

I have tried to using that addons, but it does not works at all.

Someone can help me in these case? whether using that addons, or another simple ways to do what I need to do.

I would be apreciate for any responses.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use it for all module. But You need to create a record in the ir.config.parameter.

Configuration -> Technical -> Parameters -> System Parameters

To remove the create_edit button you must add this information.

Key :"web_m2x_options.create_edit" 
Value : "false".

And to add search more on any many2one and Many2many field, you must add.

Key :"web_m2x_options.search_more" 
Value : "true".

PS: You can see more information on this github page https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/9.0/web_m2x_options

Answer (score 2):

Here i will change the default behavor of odoo to show create and edit when i want to
by using this :

```xml
       <field name="many2one_field" options="{'create':true, 'quick_create':true}"/>
```

Now under your costum module direcotry define a javascript file to change the many2one widget

```
  you_costum_module_directory_name 
        --> static
            --> src 
                  --> js
                      --> costum_many2one_widget.js
```

javascript file:

```
odoo.define('you_costum_module_directory_name.costum_many2one_widget' , function(require) {
    // I hope that you know how to add this to odoo backendassets

        // first we need core
        var core = require('web.core');
        // it's needed when we override get_search_result
        var data = require('web.data');

        // NOTE: i may forget to require some object in the code by mistake check it 

        // now we must get the many2one widget for form widget
        var FieldMany2One = core.form_widget_registry.get('many2one');

        // now we can override the method to change the behavor
        FieldMany2one.include({
            // if you want the search more to be always shown we must overrid
            // get_search_result and we need to require every thing we need first like data object
            // now to show search more always we must reimplement the 
            get_search_result: function(search_val) {
                var self = this;

                var dataset = new data.DataSet(this, this.field.relation, self.build_context());
                this.last_query = search_val;
                var exclusion_domain = [], ids_blacklist = this.get_search_blacklist();
                if (!_(ids_blacklist).isEmpty()) {
                    exclusion_domain.push(['id', 'not in', ids_blacklist]);
                }

                return this.orderer.add(dataset.name_search(
                        search_val, new data.CompoundDomain(self.build_domain(), exclusion_domain),
                        'ilike', this.limit + 1, self.build_context())).then(function(_data) {
                    self.last_search = _data;
                    // possible selections for the m2o
                    var values = _.map(_data, function(x) {
                        x[1] = x[1].split("\n")[0];
                        return {
                            label: _.str.escapeHTML(x[1].trim()) || data.noDisplayContent,
                            value: x[1],
                            name: x[1],
                            id: x[0],
                        };
                    });

                    // show search more if there is only one element at least 
                    // you can make it 0 if you want
                    if (values.length >= 1) {
                        values = values.slice(0, self.limit);
                        values.push({
                            label: _t("Search More..."),
                            action: function() {
                                dataset.name_search(search_val, self.build_domain(), 'ilike', 160).done(function(_data) {
                                    self._search_create_popup("search", _data);
                                });
                            },
                            classname: 'o_m2o_dropdown_option'
                        });
                    }
                    // if the user provide an option quick_create show quick create
                    var raw_result = _(_data.result).map(function(x) {return x[1];});
                    if (
                        search_val.length > 0 && 
                        !_.include(raw_result, search_val) &&
                        self.options && self.options.quick_create
                        ) {
                        self.can_create && values.push({
                            label: _.str.sprintf(_t('Create "<strong>%s</strong>"'),
                                $('<span />').text(search_val).html()),
                            action: function() {
                                self._quick_create(search_val);
                            },
                            classname: 'o_m2o_dropdown_option'
                        });
                    }
                    // if the user provide a create option show create and Edit option
                    if (self.options && self.options.create && self.can_create){
                        values.push({
                            label: _t("Create and Edit..."),
                            action: function() {
                                self._search_create_popup("form", undefined, self._create_context(search_val));
                            },
                            classname: 'o_m2o_dropdown_option'
                        });
                    }
                    else if (values.length === 0) {
                        values.push({
                            label: _t("No results to show..."),
                            action: function() {},
                            classname: 'o_m2o_dropdown_option'
                        });
                    }

                    return values;
                });
            }
        });


        // id don't know if this line is required or not 
        // but if we have to registre the widget again
        core.form_widget_registry.add('many2one', FieldMany2One);

    });
```

Now you need to add the js file to you backendassets template

```
you_costum_module_directory_name 
            --> static
                --> src 
                      --> js
                          --> costum_many2one_widget.js

            --> xml
                --> widgets.xml
```

add xml file to manifest :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <openerp> <!-- odoo in odoo 10.0 -->
        <data>

            <!--We need to load our js file to backend_assets-->
            <template id="assets_backend" name="many2one new edits " inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
                <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/you_costum_module_directory_name/static/src/js/costum_many2one_widget.js"></script>
                </xpath>
            </template>

        </data>
    </openerp>
```

in your manifest  `__openerp__.py` add the xml file:

Comment: sorry about my mistke when i use one2many key instead of many2one hope this help you and other  i recommand to read this tutorial with a little bit of javascript expenrience you can make odoo do what ever you want:  https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/web.html#the-form-view-custom-widgets

Comment: one thing i used the code of odoo 10 that is used to define get_search_result i don't thing it's that different from odoo 9.0 but if you have any proplem just go to web module and copy the orignal code of the method and edit it

Comment: I really apreciate for your answer, thanks bro. but i can do it first for your code to long for me, thanks

Comment: But is the hole code at once. Tell me can you add new module to you odoo?

Comment: To remove create and edit in all forms commonly, is not there any way to do it in xml?

Comment: Your js code doesn't work for me. Could you please tell me which model i must give in depends in manifest file to make it work for all forms. @Charif DZ

Answer (score 1):

You can take a slection widget to your field :

```
<field name="your_one2many_field" widget="selection"/>
```

To hide "Create and edit" use :

```
<field name="your_one2many_field" options="{'no_create_edit':True}"/>
```

Comment: What i want to do is for Every module (All) in odoo, am i must do it one by one ? or there is a way to do it once ?