# How to remove create, create and edit in all forms odoo14?

Tags: odoo

I need to remove create, create and edit in many2one fields in all forms once. If I'm using xml then it is very difficult for me to inherit each models to do it. Kindly let me know if any other shortest way to do it?

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You can try below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703386/how-to-hide-create-and-edit-button-in-all-form-odoo-and-also-search-more-but

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work for me. Thanks @himanshu.

Comment: You can do it in JS. By inheriting Many2One widget and remove the create / edit.

Comment: You can found more information in this file https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/relational_fields.js (V14). Line 125

Comment: I didn't work with js. So i need help to customize the code you sent. Thanks @jo541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a community module right for your requirement:

https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/14.0/web_m2x_options#irconfig_parameter-options

As far as i can see, the migration process to Odoo 14 version is done already, so try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the help @czoellner, I just installed the module web_m2x_options. I t didn't work. Do i need to set any variable to false in that?

Comment: create and create_edit have to be set to `False`

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the csv security file ! ,just put 0 on the create ,remove and edit perm

Comment: This is not the same thing. He juste want remove for all Many2one the create and create / edit. But allowing the possibility of creating in standard form view

Comment: i understand now thanks for the information